# What is the appropriate Apache Kafka Client jar

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

Can some one tell me the difference between the jars
[1](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.kafka/kafka-clients/0.8.2.0) and [2](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.kafka/kafka_2.9.2/0.8.2.0). I am attempting to write kafka client to pull the data from the brokers using poll(long timeout) API on the KafkaConsumer from [1](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.kafka/kafka-clients/0.8.2.0) but the implementation seems to be auto generated.(see below). Any thoughts on what is the right jar.

```
public Map<String, ConsumerRecords<K,V>> poll(long timeout) {
    return null;
}
```

Comment: The `_2.9.2` suffix on the 2nd one tells you the version of Scala it was compiled against. Since Scala isn't always backward compatible they offer jars for various Scala versions (see https://kafka.apache.org/downloads.html). Never seen one without any suffix and the dependencies for the 1st doesn't list any Scala dependencies which seems fishy so not sure what's up with that one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kafka has clients available in many programming languages. Only the Java clients are maintained as part of the main Kafka project. You can check more about [clients](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#api).

You should use 1st jar to write Kafka consumer i.e

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
    <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
    <version>0.8.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Hello @ravthiru , Thanks for the answer. Do you know the answer for my second question on the poll() API. Why would the java client has auto generated code? Thanks!

Comment: IRRC, clients got put into a own jar in Kafka 0.9 -- if Kafka 0.8.2 you need to use dependency to Kafka core.

Comment: Can you please provide the maven config for the core jar you are referring to? Not sure which one among https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.kafka  is the right one?